# Backup interruption using scp. How to exclude files just downloaded?

Tags: terminal, backup, scp, file-transfer

I need to backup a huge folder (more than 100 GB) from an external server. I use scp command in a linux terminal but connection issues happen sometimes. So I need to restart the procedure every time. Is there a way to exclude from the scp copy the folders and files just downloaded?

Comment: You may want to look at alternate solutions, such as `rsync`, which do this sort of thing automatically.

Comment: Dear Stephen, thank you for your replay. But how can I do with rsync? Because, for my knowledge, I'm able to specify folders and files to not transfer. Instead, I need an automatic procedure to recognize the folders/files just donwloaded.